# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android

Всем привет! Прошу помощи! Никак не могу разобраться своей проблемой. Возникает ошибка при попытке отрисовать фрагмент, на котором расположен CardView.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
```

CardView добавлен в gradle файл!:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

Воспроизводится на андроиде ниже пятой версии.
Создал новый проект, добавил CardView - все работает без проблем.
Пробовал чистить проект, пересобирал куча раз, импортировал как новый проект, чистил кеш, ничего не помогает! Уже не знаю в чем может быть дело. Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorActivityBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_view_ripple">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text1"
                android:textColor="#767676"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:typeface="roboto_medium" />

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:typeface="roboto_medium" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue_selector"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:textColor="@color/button_color" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте во время компиляции посмотреть на *deprecation warning*  или почитайте отчеты **lint** - с этими суппорт либами крайне мутная история - от версии к версии меняются `minSdk`, но в документации об этом крайне мало инфы.

Comment: @Barmaley к сожалению никаких deprecation warning нет. :(

Comment: @zimper Покажите, как добавляете CardView на  экран

Comment: Да, тогда покажите свой лейаут и поройтесь в `build/reports/lint-results*.html`

Comment: @Barmaley, добавил разметку фрагмента

Comment: @zimper   android:foreground="@drawable/card_view_ripple" сомнительно выглядит. Попробуйте удалить эту строку и запустить приложение

Comment: @Ramil Gabdrakhmanov, Вы - чудо. Это помогло.

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov оформляйте как ответ :)

Comment: ripple-эффекты доступны только с API21

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что стоит попробовать удалить строку `android:foreground="@drawable/card_view_ripple"`  в лейауте. Если после этого проблема уйдет, например, разделить этот ресурс для прелолипопа и лолипопа

Answer (score 0):

Let import cardview as a library: 
Go to File -> Import -> Existing Android code into workspace --> Browse (Go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/cardview) --> Click ok --> Click Finish

Your project explorer will now show cardview as a project.

Right click on cardview project --> Properties --> Android(Left Pane) --> Enable isLibrary (tick the checkbox) --> Apply --> ok

Now Right click on your project --> Properties --> Android(Left pane) --> Add (under library) --> cardview --> apply --> ok

Now right click on your project again --> build path --> configure build path --> Under projects tab, add cardview

You are done.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! здесь принят для общения русский язык. исправить ответ можно, нажав [edit]